# cannot release objects after retrieving from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am still stacked with a simple objC code which retrieve some data from plist. After I used them I cannot release object because it fails...

```
- (void)retrieveFromPlist:(NSString*)Nazov
{
NSLog(@"Objekt: %@",Nazov);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"working.plist"];
////Zober vsetky ulozene

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
subDict = [dict objectForKey:Nazov];

NSString                    *hudbaR;
float                       hudbaL;
NSString                    *zvukR;
float                       zvukL;


hudbaL = [[subDict objectForKey:@"musicLevel"] floatValue];
hudbaR = [subDict objectForKey:@"musicRow"];
zvukL = [[subDict objectForKey:@"soundLevel"] floatValue];
zvukR = [subDict objectForKey:@"soundRow"];

NSLog(@"Musical level: %f, musical roww:%@ , zuk level: %f, zuk row: %@", hudbaL,hudbaR ,zvukL ,zvukR );



if (hudbaR) {
    [musicController setBackgroundSoundVolume:zvukL];
    [musicController setBackgroundMusicVolume:hudbaL];

    MusicsliderCtl.value = hudbaL;
    sliderCtl.value = zvukL;


    [musicController playMusicWithKey:hudbaR timesToRepeat:0];  
    [musicController playSoundWithKey:zvukR timesToRepeat:0];

}   

//[dict release];
//[subDict release];
}
```

Comment: What does "fail" mean? Also, could you please edit the post to look a bit nicer (use the code block for the whole code).

Comment: Are the release calls inside the scope of the retrieveFromPlist method? It is hard to tell because of th formatting problems. If not, move them into the method where you declare the dictionaries. Otherwise you are trying to use out of scope variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
subDict = [dict objectForKey:Nazov];
```

The 2nd statement overrides the already allocated subDict. This causes memory leak. Then because you don't own the `[dict objectForKey:Nazov]`, `-release`ing it causes deallocation error.

You could just write

```
NSDictionary* subDict = [dict objectForKey:Nazov];
```

and don't `-release` it since you are not the owner. (`[dict release]` is still needed as you are the one who `+alloc` it.)

If you're not changing the collection, prefer immutable (NSDictionary) over mutable (NSMutableDictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to release an autoreleased object (subDict) that your code doesn't have ownership over:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
subDict = [dict objectForKey:Nazov];
```

The originally `subDict` variable is being overwritten by the return value from the `objectForKey:` message. Resulting in first a leak of the original object and then a crash when the autorelease pool tries to release the new object.

In order to correct this, remove the following lines in your code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
...
[subDict release];
```